# Ruby - combine certain elements of arrays into a new array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm trying to merge certain elements of arrays into one array.

I have the following:

```
arr1: ["element1":"ABC", "element1":"DEF","element1":"GHI"]
arr2: ["element2":"123", "element2":"456", "element2":"789"]
arr3: ["element3":"JKL", "element3":"MNO", "element3":"PQR"]
```

I'm trying to merge each of the first elements into an array, then the second, then the third, to produce:

```
arr4: ["element1":"ABC", "element2":"123", "element3":"JKL"]
arr5: ["element1":"DEF", "element2":"456", "element3":"MNO"]
arr6: ["element1":"GHI", "element2":"789", "element3":"PQR"]
```

The code I have at the moment is:

```
test1 = ["element1:"+arr1[0] +', "element2:"'+ arr2[0] + ', "element3:" '+arr3[0]]
test2 = ["element1:"+arr1[1] +', "element2:"'+ arr2[1] + ', "element3:" '+arr3[1]]
test3 = ["element1:"+arr1[2] +', "element2:"'+ arr2[2] + ', "element3:" '+arr3[2]]
```

But then I get a mess of a result - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your data makes no sense. Your `["element1":"ABC", "element1":"DEF","element1":"GHI"]` for example actually is `[{:element1=>"GHI"}]`.

Answer (score 3):

```
arr1 = ["ABC", "DEF", "GHI"]
arr2 = ["123", "456", "789"]
arr3 = ["JKL", "MNO", "PQR"]
```

Use [Array#transpose](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose) with parallel assignment.

```
arr4, arr5, arr6 = [arr1, arr2, arr3].transpose

arr4 #=> ["ABC", "123", "JKL"]
arr5 #=> ["DEF", "456", "MNO"]
arr6 #=> ["GHI", "789", "PQR"]
```

Comment: Hmm, your input and output look quite different from the question's.

Comment: @Stefan The OP had (albeit with a few syntax errors) the arrays I present in my answer. Unfortunately you can't see this in the edit-history for the question. Anyway, the general idea here is the important thing I hope:)

Comment: Ok... just looks weird. And why would they vandalize their own question like that... sigh.

Answer (score 2):

[Array#transpose](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose) and [Array#zip](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-zip) are [yin and yang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yin_and_yang). Whenever `transpose` can be used, `zip` is an alternative. The reverse is also true if the arrays `arr1`, `arr2` and `arr3` are all the same size (as required by `transpose`, but not by `zip`).

```
arr1.zip(arr2, arr3)
  #=> [["ABC", "123", "JKL"],
  #    ["DEF", "456", "MNO"],
  #    ["GHI", "789", "PQR"]]
```